# Spring Boot - AJAX But Limited To Internal Use

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm wondering if it's possible to make an AJAX call without the path being available to anyone who knows the URL. For example lets say I've the following code:

```
@GetMapping("/responsebody")
@ResponseBody
public UserAccount testingResponseBody(Principal principal) {
    if(principal != null) {
        UserAccount currentUser = userRepo.findByUserName(principal.getName());
        return currentUser;
    }else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As far as I'm aware, this allows anyone who types in "/responsebody" in the search bar to be able to see the corresponding JSON.

But what if I don't want the corresponding data to be available to the public what do I do then. I just want to use it internally in the application.

I'm new to Spring boot and all this so i'd really appreciate if sombody could clear things up for me.

Thanks

Comment: do you want to use the user principle means user name etc?

Comment: @BlackSwan in this case yes